# How many intervals are containing an another interval?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, intervals

There are given N intervals, with start and end points. How many pairs of these intervals exists, such that one interval is containing the another interval?

For example, if the given intervals are:
`{2,3},{1,5},{0,10},{2,4}`
then we have 5 pairs:
`{0,10}` contains `{2,3}`
`{0,10}` contains `{2,4}`
`{0,10}` contains `{1,5}`
`{1,5}` contains `{2,4}`
`{1,5}` contains `{2,3}`

We are interested just in the number of such pairs. Can you help me finding at least an `O(N log N)` solution(the `O(N^2)` is trivial)?

Note: The intervals are given in a form of `{startpoint,endpoint}`, where startpoint and endpoint can be up to 10^18.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by `startpoint`, count the number of inversions in the list of `endpoint`s using the mergesort-derived O(n log n)-time algorithm.